# Javascript Functions

Tags: javascript, function, this

I'm very new to Javascript and somewhere i found this code

```
  var myObject = {
            value: 0,
            increment: function (inc) {
                this.value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
            }
   };
```

In the above object the **increment** function is acessing the **value** variable using **this**. But in languages like java, the public method can access the private member without this also.. why it is not possible here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every JS function has a reference to a chain of scopes, in which it tries to lookup the variables. This chain is as follow:

- local variables of current function
- local variables of function that called it
- (...)
- global variables

The current object (and its fields) is not in the chain, so you have to reference it with `this`.

Comment: Do u mean scope is the problem? fucntions are in different scope?

Answer (score 1):

Because **value** is trying to get a variable named **value** in the global scope, and here you are in an object and this is a property of the object.

Answer (score 0):

Because this is Javascript, and not Java. There is no relation or similarity between the two languages, even though Javascript has "Java" in its name.

Answer (score 0):

It's because of your scope... you could try it like this:

```
var myObject = (function(){
    var value = 0,
        increment = function (inc) {
            value += typeof inc === 'number' ? inc : 1;
            return value;
        };
    return {increment:increment}
})();
console.log(myObject.increment());
console.log(myObject.increment());
console.log(myObject.increment());
```

Comment: You did not understand the question!

Comment: Yes - the code is working - he is asking why he needs the **this** part